# Why can I reject an edit that doesn't touch the tags with the reason "irrelevant tags"?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

Well, as the title says: Why is it possible to reject an edit that does nothing to the tags for introducing irrelevant tags?

Here's visual proof that this is possible:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the rejection reasons don't vary in the review of suggested edits on the posts (suggested edits on tags have different set of rejections reasons).

The reason you are talking about was introduced in the [new set of reasons](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/) and, *still*, this set doesn't vary from post to post.

I don't find it to be a real problem; just don't choose this reason when not applicable.